# How to stream my screen using rtsp (like ip camera)?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, camera, mplayer

Hy all,

At work, we migrated all computers at ubuntu 18.04. Before migration, we used windows 10 and Desk Camera app to recording screens and we used that to put in NVR like a IP Camera for recording, scroll back etc. We tried using wine and install desk camera but we can't pass the microsoft 4.5 framework step. Anyway, we tried different methods with vlc but no results. I finded on this forum a solution with mplayer and ffmpeg but i didn't finded a tutorial step by step.
Can help me, please? Or a different solution, it will be great!

Thank you in advance!